# Jquery scripts not working with bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I'm currently using bootstrap 4 and been looking for answers but I can't seem to find it. My scripts are not working, specifically, the smooth scroll script. I used the live links for the bootstraps and jquery because even the offline files won't work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>


</head>

<body>

    <header>
      <!-- Fixed navbar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md  navbar-light fixed-top">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home"> <img src="images/logo_final.ico" width="50" height="50" class="d-inline-block" alt="">Importante Ka Ba?</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#parentstyle">Parenting Styles</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#stories">Stories</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>


<div id="home">

<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="left col-sm-6"></div>
        <div class="right col-sm-6">
        <h1> Game
         ka na ba makita ang teenage angst ng panahong ito?
        <hr style="background-color: red;">
        <a class="btn" href="#parentstyle" type="button"  >Game na!</a>
        </h1>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>




<div id="parentstyle">

<div class="container-fluid">
<h1> adfa </h1>
</div>
</div>




<div id="stories">

<div class="container-fluid">
<h1> adfa </h1>
</div>
</div>



<div id="articles">

<div class="container-fluid">
<h1> adfa </h1>
</div>
</div>


 <footer class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <span class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</span>
      </div>
    </footer>


<!--script-->


<script>
$("html").easeScroll();
</script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easeScroll.js"></script>




</body>
```

below is the css that I used in case that it might be conflicting with the codes.

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */


@font-face {
    font-family: over;
    src: url("../fonts/over.ttf");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: coco;
    src: url("../fonts/coco.ttf");
}


* { 
margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
      background:transparent;
  background-image:none;
  border-color:transparent;
  box-shadow:none;
}

.navbar-brand {
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.left {
    height: 100vh;
    float: left;
    background-image: url(../images/homebg2.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
}

.right {
    height: 100vh;
    float: right;
    background-image: url(../images/homebg.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
}

.right h1 {
    text-align: center;
   position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-family: coco;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: white;
}

#home .btn {
    background-color: #ffce2d;
    font-family: over;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: black;
} 


#stories {
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url("http://hdqwalls.com/wallpapers/city-minimalism-sv.jpg");
    padding-top: 60px;
        background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

}


#parentstyle {
    padding-top: 60px;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/2b/19/fb/2b19fb4193506a0d5119beace69d7551.png" );
        background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}


#articles {
    padding-top: 60px;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: gray;
        background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 950px) {
    .left, .right {
        float: none !important;
    }

    .right {
        background-image: none !important;
        background-color: #f6d6c1;
    }

    .right h1{
        color: #170C60 !important;
    }

    .navbar {
        background-color: white;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change some rules.

Swap:

```
<script>
$("html").easeScroll();
</script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

With:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easeScroll.js"></script>

<script>
$("html").easeScroll();
</script>
```

You are trying to use easeScroll before it has loaded/ initialized.